# Win32 C/C++ add a button to desktop

Tags: c, controls, desktop, draw, win32gui

Hi long time ago I saw a program made in C++ that created a button and docked in on the top left corner of the desktop so that the Desktop itself was re-sized to accommodate the new control. But I forgot which API the guy used.

Does anybody know what I;m talking about or have any experience with drawing controls on the Desktop ?

Thanks.

PS: I just need the APIs

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")

#include <shellapi.h>

void    pumpMsg(MSG * msg){


while(GetMessage(msg,0,0,0) != 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(msg);
    DispatchMessage(msg);
}

}


WNDPROC oldProc = 0;

HWND hWnd = 0;

APPBARDATA abd = {0};

BOOL CALLBACK dlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wpar, LPARAM lpar)
{
if(msg==WM_COMMAND)
{
    if(wpar==100)
    {
        puts("Called");
        SendMessage(hwnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
    }

}

if(msg==WM_CLOSE || msg==WM_QUIT)
{
    SHAppBarMessage(ABM_REMOVE, &abd);
    EndDialog(hwnd,1);
}

CallWindowProc(oldProc,hwnd,msg,wpar,lpar);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
MSG msg = {0}; 

    DWORD style = WS_VISIBLE|WS_SYSMENU;
hWnd =  CreateWindowEx(0,WC_DIALOG,"",style,2,2,400,400,0,0,GetModuleHandle(0),0);
__asm mov ebx, eax



       abd.cbSize = sizeof(APPBARDATA); 
       abd.hWnd = hWnd;
       SHAppBarMessage(ABM_NEW, &abd); 
       abd.rc.top = 0; 
       abd.rc.left = 0; 
       abd.rc.right = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN); 
       abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + 60; 

       abd.uEdge = ABE_TOP; 

       SHAppBarMessage(ABM_QUERYPOS, &abd); 
       SHAppBarMessage(ABM_SETPOS, &abd); 
       abd.lParam = TRUE;
       SHAppBarMessage(ABM_ACTIVATE, &abd);

       MoveWindow(hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, TRUE);

        CreateWindowEx(0,"button","button",WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,2,10,40,40,hWnd,(HMENU)100,GetModuleHandle(0),0);

__asm{

    push    dlgProc
    push    GWL_WNDPROC
    push    ebx
    call    [SetWindowLong]

    mov     [oldProc],  eax
    }

 DWORD tid = 0;

// CreateThread(0,0,&Timer,0,0,&tid);

 pumpMsg(&msg);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [Application Desktop Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776821%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The magic function is [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok. Uuhhm, I'm looking at the examples online and most of them don't add controls to it just ends up black. Do you happen to know how to add a simple control like a button? Thanks

Comment: You can put whatever you want in your appbar. If you want to put a button in it, knock yourself out.

Comment: I understand but how do you practically do it because all I see is the same identical code(which looks like Copy & Paste)all over the net and the authors don't add any controls at all. It just shows up as a blank .

Like, where and when do you exactly add a control to it? Here's my flow **I create main window, on initialization of the main window I create the APPBAR and call all the appropriate indexed functions(i.e ABM_NEW to ABM_ACTIVAE. But I don't know when and where to add a new control because there's no handle associated with it. The only handle I can tamper with is the parent window**

Comment: The window you passed in the `APPBARDATA.hWnd` member? That's your appbar window. Add your controls to that window.

Comment: I'm really getting mad now. The window will appear as an appbar every other time the program is run. The other it won't, it just shows up like a normal window. I'm calling ABD_REMOVE too. Let me just post the code up here.

Comment: So do you think it could be because I'm using a Dialog class ?